# Check Select year parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select year which I wanna check if the year matches:

```
<%= select_year(Date.today, {start_year: 2015, end_year: Date.today.year} %>
```

The default name is date[year] and I wanna compare the value in the query like:

```
where("YEAR(date) = ?", x)
```

Where x would be the year, but I can't get it to work. I'm passing it from the controller like:

```
@result = Model.function(params[:date][:year])
```

But I keep getting "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" even though I see it passing "Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "date"=>{"year"=>"2015"}}"

Comment: Have you permitted the date and year attributes with the strong_params method in your controller?

Comment: No, cause it's a param I get from a form, pass it to a function to do a select, I guess it doesn't need to be whitelisted

Comment: Can you post your full code from the controller action please

Comment: Using a select_tag it works, using a name like "year", I just can't make it work when it's into an array like date[year]

Comment: @Lamandaas, please try to get year like this **params['date']['year']**

Comment: Doesn't work: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Post the full controller code and your view (the form) too.